# grails 3.3: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException with findOrSaveWhere

Tags: hibernate, grails

In bootstrap.goovy, we need to create the static/test database records if they don't already exist (i.e. created when app was previously run)

```
 def admin1 =  Operator.findOrSaveWhere(username: "admin", password: "test", firstName: "admin", lastName: "admin", email: "a@b.com")
```

This creates the record if it doesn't exist, or read it if it does.  Great.

The problem comes when we want to use admin1 as a field in another sql statement, e.g.

```
  def note1 =  Note.findOrSaveWhere(user: user1, operator: operator1, note: "This is a note. Pretty dull. User is Boib. you can trust him 1")
```

This fails with:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: come.me.myapp.Operator
```

findOrSaveWhere presumably has just created the operator, but its not flushed to the DB.

normally, if you use admin1.save(flush:true), it would solve this issue. Is there a way to flush something created with findOrSaveWhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `findOrCreateWhere`:

```
def admin1 =  Operator.findOrCreateWhere( yadda:yadda, tadda:tadda )
if( !admin1.id ) admin.save flush:true
def note1 =  Note.findOrSaveWhere(user: admin1)
```

Another option:

You should put your code in bootstrap in explicit transaction `Operator.withTransaction{...}` then your original code should work.